# double byte swapping

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

There are some discussions about the same question but I would like to ask some more ,

1) How portable is the below code for a double byte swapping

```
int ReadDouble(FILE *fptr,double *n)
{
   unsigned char *cptr,tmp;

   if (fread(n,8,1,fptr) != 1)
      return(FALSE);

   cptr = (unsigned char *)n;
   tmp = cptr[0];
   cptr[0] = cptr[7];
   cptr[7] = tmp;
   tmp = cptr[1];
   cptr[1] = cptr[6];
   cptr[6] = tmp;
   tmp = cptr[2];
   cptr[2] = cptr[5];
   cptr[5] =tmp;
   tmp = cptr[3];
   cptr[3] = cptr[4];
   cptr[4] = tmp;

   return(TRUE);
}
```

2) Should I keep the 3 important parts of a floating point number, sign bit, mantissa, exponent as integers and then try to manipulate them somehow.

I know the basics of floating point representations, not that deeply as a mechanical engineer, however I need to read some big-endian file where my machine is little endian. I can maybe worry about the portability issues later on. But I would like to learn about them perhaps you can direct me to some more direct things on this because there is too much information on this, I was confused which one to read.

So after some comments this should more or less do that in a portable way right? Sorry for the C file pointers...

```
double_t ReadDouble(ifstream& source) {
  // read 
  char buf[sizeof(double_t)];
  source.read(buf, sizeof(double_t));
  // reverse and return
  reverse( buf, buf+sizeof(double_t) );
  return *(reinterpret_cast<double_t*>(buf));
}
```

Best,
Umut

Comment: Do you know the input will always be big-endian?

Comment: Yes, apparently the commercial software generates the binary files in  big-endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not as easy as that. Just because an architecture is big-endian for integers doesn't mean it's big-endian for floating point numbers. I've heard of platforms that store integers big-endian and floats little-endian.
So first you should discover what the actual memory representation of double on your source platform is.

As for the swap itself, it's inefficient and way too much code. An additional 8-byte buffer won't kill you, so why not do this:

```
int ReadDouble(FILE* f, double* n) {
  unsigned char* nbytes = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(n);
  unsigned char buf[sizeof(double)];
  if (fread(buf, sizeof(double), 1, f) != 1) return FALSE;

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(double); ++i) {
    nbytes[i] = buf[sizeof(double)-1-i];
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Way less code, even if you decide to manually unroll the loop.

Comment: Could replace the reverse loop with a call to `std::reverse` from `<algorithm>`.

Comment: why don't you read directly into the `reinterpret_cast` pointer and then call `std::reverse` as @birryree says.. You avoid the extra buffer then... (btw. your `fread` should take `sizeof(double)` rather than `8`)

Comment: double_t ReadDouble(ifstream& source) {
  // read 
  char buf[sizeof(double_t)];
  source.read(buf, sizeof(double_t));
  // reverse and return
  reverse( buf, buf+sizeof(double_t) );
  return *(reinterpret_cast<double_t*>(buf));
}

Comment: Thanks for the sizeof(double) oversight.

Comment: I specifically don't do in-place reverse because doing a reverse-as-you-copy is more efficient. Reversing in-place requires you to do 50% more copy operations. (3 for every 2 bytes) This is of course dependent on the whole size - if the datatype to reverse is large, then the copy is significant, but in this case the buffer is tiny and on the stack, so I claim that when you call the function a lot, my version would be a tiny bit faster. Of course, only profiling can prove such a claim, and you have overhead to deal with. I think C++0x has reverse_copy, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

This is not portable because you are not checking the order of your machine vs. the expected order in the file.  If the machine matches the file, then you are swapping bytes to the wrong order.

One easy way to check is to look at the bit representation of a known constant.